# Cannot amplify DC voltage using op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, dc, dc-dc-converter, 741-opamp

I am trying to amplify a DC voltage scaled from 5-10V to another DC voltage with maximum 12V. Why I am not using just a DC voltage with that value? Because the input DC is variable according to some other parameters. All what matters is that we have a DC and we just want to amplify it (without inverting it.)

I have implemented 3 circuits to accomplish this, and the 3 circuits failed to give the required output. The maximum voltage I could get is 10.78V no matter the ratio between resistors is. I tried so many resistors even with different configurations to yield a ratio of 0.25 to 0.4, the required is 0.31.

The three circuits are shown below:

First Circuit:

[image: 1]

Second Circuit:

[image: 2]

Third Circuit:

[image: 3]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136664/discussion-on-question-by-m-125-cannot-amplify-dc-voltage-using-op-amps).

Comment: If all you want to do is multiply your input by 1.33, and your input ranges between 5V and 10V, that the only thing you need to do to fix your circuit is connect pin-4 of your 741(the negative supply) to ground. That's it. Leave everything else as-is.

Comment: @M-125 To the same node of the circuit. In the first 2 circuits the negative terminal of the power source should be connected to the two "ground" nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your first circuit is that you did not connect the negative power supply pin of the op-amp to ground. You have been informed multiple times that the power supply needs to be interconnected with ground, and circuit 1 fails to do so.

The main problem with your second circuit is the same.

The main problem with the third circuit is that, although you have interconnected ground and the power supply, you only have 9V above ground being applied to the op-amp positive power pin. You have split the 12V so that ground is half way between them. +6V and -6V. Then you added another 3V to the positive to get +9V. A secondary problem is that the way you have created a split supply by using 51 k\$\Omega\$ resistors is very far from being ideal.

In your previous questions you asserted that you only had 12V to work with. Now you have more, but you need to apply the other information that has been given to you.

Other answers give examples of power supply configurations that will work.

Comment: I did not downvoter, but you may have received downvoted because two of your circuits had problems identical to problems seen in previous questions you posed.

Comment: Why don't you just connect pin 4 to ground in your first two schematics? Why are you even trying to split a 12V supply into +/- 6 volts when you can apparently add only 3 more?

Comment: Don't change anything else, but connect pin 4 to ground. Since the negative terminal of the battery is already connected to pin 4 it will thus automatically become connected to ground when pin 4 does. However, when drawing it, you could connect both pin 4 and the negative terminal both to ground. This will automatically connect pin 4 to the negative terminal of the battery, since when two things are connected to the same node (ground in this case) they are connected to each other.

Comment: I am somewhat frustrated with you as well. Instead of asking the good question "why do I need to connect the power supply to ground in this circuit?" (Which you said you would do, and which would have probably clarified a lot for you) you instead continued experimenting repeating the same mistake. So you are not the only one who is frustrated.

Comment: You might want to ask, as a separate question, "why is the output current so small in this circuit"? I will not explain in a comment, because comments are not for tutorials. But I will give you a little teaser. That question is directly related to the question "why do I need to connect my power supply to ground in this circuit?"

Comment: If you are confused, ask a separate question. Comments are not for tutorials. Your question could be "people keep telling me to connect pin 4 to ground, but it doesn't appear to make any difference to me. Is there a difference?"

Comment: @SamGibson would it be ok or not if I posted essentially the same question? I would like to give M-125 a tutorial, but don't want to do it in the comments. If me asking the question would be bad form, or appear as evasion of the rules, then obviously I will wait until M-125's question limit has expired.

Comment: MathKeepsMeBusy - That's completely OK, in fact that's a good solution in this situation. Thanks. (This is a repost of the relevant part of an earlier, now deleted-as-obsolete, comment so that my reply to that comment is still visible here.)

Comment: M-125 Please check out https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/621542/268467

Answer (score 2):

Your problems are basically with your power supply voltages.

Your first circuit uses a single 15-volt supply which is not directly tied to any part of the circuit such as ground. Same with your second circuit. Your third circuit uses R13/R14 to produce a nominal +/- 6 volts. Then you add 3 volts to the +6, resulting in something like 9 volts at the op amp.

741s are not noted for wide voltage swings. With +/- 15 volt supplies, some are not rated to produce much more than 10 volts. With no way to check you models, assuming the - supply on your first figure was tied to ground, 10.3 does not surprising. On your third, with +9/-6 (assuming no changes due to the op amp actually drawing current - which is not going to be true), you simply won't be able to get more than about 6 or 7 volts out.

So how to fix? Change your power supplies. In this case, use something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkH6jG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "standard" 741 power supply setup +/- 15 volts simply is not guaranteed to provide the 12.2 volts you are looking at. It might work or it might not.

Comment: @M-125 The difference between +9 and -6 is 15, though....

Comment: @M-125 You tried using a higher positive supply?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast good catch. I think it's actually supposed to be ±15 not just ±6 which is obviously far too low to get a 10V output.

Comment: @M-125 If you measure from one rail to the other you get  15V (approximately). But if you measure the positive rail relative to _ground_ you would only get about 9V ( if your voltage divider resistors were not the excessively high 51 k\$\Omega\$ that you have). It is the voltage above _ground_ that matters, and not just the voltage difference between the two supply pins. Since the manner in which you connect your power supply to ground is really bad, you might see something above 9V, but any semblance of the circuit working near properly is a lucky accident.

Comment: @M-125 - Shrug. Sorry, but your schematic is very clear. If your 12-volt supply is floating (as you show) and your op amp isn't drawing much current, then you will get +/- 6 volts at the op amp. I notice in the other two circuits that the supplies also appear to be floating.  Have you tied the - of the supply to ground in each case - AND NOT TOLD US?

Answer (score 0):

You start by writing clear I/O specs and observe limits to both.

Then compute gain and mean or offset separately.

Instead of a 0V reference for gain, you will need something else for offset. Then determine R values for offset then Rfb for attenuation or overall gain 1+ Rfb/Req(in-)

12Vout is possible with V+=15 but the Vout cannot go to V-=0V with a 741 type but rail to rail CMOS OP-Amps exist.

Comment: You need to define  minimum voltage so gain and offset is realized. Like 4 to 12V from input 5 to 10 don't assume we should know it is 5 to12, then do as I said compute gain and offset, whats the confusion with that?